# How to print help to stdout?

Tags: python, stdout

```
help(help)
```

does not print to stdout, but open an interactive screen to scroll up and down. How to directly print the help page to stdout? Thanks.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but in Bash on Debian/Ubuntu, `LESS=XF pydoc help` does something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`plainpager`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd8ca9aaccef0569c4b5c2e6dad0feb869ffd6c5/Lib/pydoc.py#L1590):

```
import pydoc
pydoc.pager = pydoc.plainpager
help(help)
```